# The spacing when using arabic counter as the tabularnote index

Tags: nicematrix

Is there a way to let `arabic` counter have the same spacing as with `alph`?

MWE

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

{
\NiceMatrixOptions{
    notes={
        style = \alph{#1}
    }
}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cc}
    a & b\tabularnote{test}
\end{NiceTabular}
}

{
\NiceMatrixOptions{
    notes={
        style = \arabic{#1}
    }
}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cc}
    a & b\tabularnote{test}
\end{NiceTabular}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of notes at the end of the tabular is composed with a list of `enumitem`. In your case, you should probably want to use the setting `widest*=1` of `enumitem` to change that list. It's possible to provide that setting with the key `enumitem-keys` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

{
\NiceMatrixOptions{
    notes={
        style = \alph{#1} ,
        enumitem-keys = { widest* = 1 }
    }
}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cc}
    a & b\tabularnote{test}
\end{NiceTabular}
}

{
\NiceMatrixOptions{
    notes={
        style = \arabic{#1} ,
        enumitem-keys = { widest* = 1 }
    }
}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cc}
    a & b\tabularnote{test} 
\end{NiceTabular}
}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thank you for point this out. I am now using `enumitem-keys = { widest = m}` which is the default for `\alph`. For others who might be interested, please check out [Section 3.2 Horizontal spacing of labels] of the enumitem docs.